# Optimize query multiple left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to optimize this query:

```
SELECT m.*,
       m1.act_value   AS m1_login,
       m2.act_description AS m2_logout,
       m3.act_description           AS m3.warning
FROM   message m
       LEFT JOIN message_detail m1
              ON m.id = m1.message
                 AND m1.type= 'login'
                 AND m1.id_message = m.id
       LEFT JOIN message_detail m2 
              ON m.id = m2.message
                 AND m2.type= 'logout'
                 AND m2.id_message = m.id
       LEFT JOIN message_detail m3 
              ON m.id = m3.message
                 AND m3.type= 'warning'
                 AND m3.id_message = m.id
WHERE  m.state = 'SEND'
       AND m.time= 'Y'
       AND m.ip <> '192.168.1.2'
GROUP  BY m.id
ORDER  BY m.id
```

have you any ideas?

I want to perform a LEFT JOIN. How can I do this?

Comment: This query already has 3 left joins.  Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: Publish your table definitions so we can see what indexes you have in place together with an explain plan.

Comment: I wan to use less LEFT JOIN and reduce the speed of query

Comment: The query is malformed and is producing unpredictable results, due the non-aggregated columns in the select list that are not present in the `GROUP BY` clause. This [malformed] query can only run in MySQL 5.7.5 or older. Please fix the query first.

Comment: Also, consider that MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life next year, so it worth considering an upgrade to MySQL 8.x soon. However, you'll need to consider that a [bad] query like this one won't even run in 8.x.

Comment: Can we assume that message.id is unique and indexed? Is there only one line of each ID for each type ie never more than 1 line login, 1 line logout and 1 line warning for any given id. How many lines do you have and how long is the query taking?

Comment: I see `message` and `id_message` -- both in `message_detail`; perhaps a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluntly speaking, it is a clumsy schema design to have so many tables.  And it is the notorious EAV pattern.

Here's a better formulation without changing anything.  It moves the `LEFT JOINs` into the `SELECT` part and avoids the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT m.*,
       ( SELECT act_value       FROM message_detail
            WHERE message = m.id AND type = 'login'  ) AS login,
       ( SELECT act_description FROM message_detail
            WHERE message = m.id AND type = 'logout' ) AS description,
       ( SELECT act_value       FROM message_detail
            WHERE message = m.id AND type = 'warning') AS act_description
FROM message AS m
    WHERE  m.state = 'SEND'
      AND  m.time= 'Y'
      AND  m.ip <> '192.168.1.2'
    ORDER BY  m.id
```

And you need these indexes:

```
message:  INDEX(state, time)
message_detail:  INDEX(message, type)
```

What is the `PRIMARY KEY` for `message_detail`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE message_detail` so I can advise on a bit more speedup by changing the PK.

Answer (score 0):

You should use aggregation functions, since you already group. And then you can just join the `message_detail` table once, and distinguish using a `CASE..WHEN` expression:

```
SELECT m.id,
       MIN(CASE WHEN m1.type = 'login' THEN m1.act_value END)   AS m1_login,
       MIN(CASE WHEN m1.type = 'logout' THEN m1.act_description END) AS m2_logout,
       MIN(CASE WHEN m1.type = 'warning' THEN m1.act_description END) AS m3.warning
FROM   message m
       LEFT JOIN message_detail m1
              ON m.id = m1.message
                 AND m1.type in ('login', 'logout', 'warning')
                 AND m1.id_message = m.id
WHERE  m.state = 'SEND'
       AND m.time= 'Y'
       AND m.ip <> '192.168.1.2'
GROUP  BY m.id
ORDER  BY m.id
```

Note that in your `SELECT` clause you should either use values that are grouped by (or functionally dependent on them), **or** use some aggregation. So `m.*` is not good practice here, and would not be allowed on SQL standard compliant databases. See [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) info on that topic and the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting.